# spring-boot 2 with jolokia: how to disable authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

ENV: springboot 2.0.5.RELEASE, jolokia 1.5.0

How to disable `jokolia` authentication?
Endpoint `jolokia` response looks like following:

```
{
  "request": {
    "type": "version"
  },
  "value": {
    "agent": "1.5.0",
    "protocol": "7.2",
    "config": {
      "listenForHttpService": "true",
      "authIgnoreCerts": "false",
      "agentId": "172.22.0.3-7-72f8afb3-servlet",
      "debug": "false",
      "agentType": "servlet",
      "policyLocation": "classpath:/jolokia-access.xml",
      "agentContext": "/jolokia",
      "serializeException": "false",
      "mimeType": "text/plain",
      "dispatcherClasses": "org.jolokia.http.Jsr160ProxyNotEnabledByDefaultAnymoreDispatcher",
      "authMode": "basic",
      "streaming": "true",
      "canonicalNaming": "true",
      "historyMaxEntries": "10",
      "allowErrorDetails": "true",
      "allowDnsReverseLookup": "true",
      "realm": "jolokia",
      "includeStackTrace": "true",
      "useRestrictorService": "false",
      "debugMaxEntries": "100"
    },
    "info": {
      "product": "tomcat",
      "vendor": "Apache",
      "version": "8.5.34"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": 1538476345,
  "status": 200
}
```

Same user application environment with springboot 1.5.9.RELEASE and jokolia 1.3.7 no authentication necessary. Endpoint `jokolia` responds like following:

```
{
  "request": {
    "type": "version"
  },
  "value": {
    "agent": "1.3.7",
    "protocol": "7.2",
    "config": {
      "agentId": "172.27.0.2-6-57fcc568-servlet",
      "agentType": "servlet"
    },
    "info": {
      "product": "tomcat",
      "vendor": "Apache",
      "version": "8.5.23"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": 1538487291,
  "status": 200
}
```

Comment: Both responses seem to be a 200 OK. It's not clear that one has required authentication while the other has not. Can you provide some more details? A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Comment: Authentication is required if one asks e.g. `/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage`. I kinda hoped for some configurations under `management.endpoint.jolokia.config`. Only `debug` is mentioned there. My application is using keycloak oauth. I'll find a mcv example.

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure Jolokia's security policy to control which operations require authentication. There's more information in [Jolokia's documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/security.html#security-policy).

Comment: Quote from Jolokia doc: "4.1.7. Policy Location: If a classpath lookup fails then access is globally granted and a warning is given on standard output." `classpath:/jolokia-access.xml` definitely not there.

Comment: Warning is there `jolokia-actuator-endpoint: No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed`. What can one do with `management.endpoint.jolokia.config`?

Comment: `management.endpoint.jolokia.config` can be used to configure anything that's supported by Jolokia's init parameters. They are described in [Jolokia's documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html). If you'd like some more help, a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) is going to be needed. It's not clear to me exactly what's not working and why from your description.

Comment: Solved using ignoring management port altogether. I was using `web.ignoring().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())`. It seems like it only matches requests to level of those endpoints, but not levels deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the file `jolokia-access.xml` in `src/main/resources` so that it is part of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from my comment: Solved using ignoring management port altogether. I was using `web.ignoring().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())`. It seems like it only matches requests to the level of those endpoints, but not levels deeper.